# Is there an assertException in any of the Haskell test frameworks?

Tags: testing, haskell

I'm writing some tests using HUnit and I would like to assert that a particular function throws an exception given a certain input. I can't find an assert function which provides the required functionality. Anyone know of a test framework that does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although HUnit doesn't come with any exception assertions, it's easy to write your own:

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Test.HUnit

assertException :: (Exception e, Eq e) => e -> IO a -> IO ()
assertException ex action =
    handleJust isWanted (const $ return ()) $ do
        action
        assertFailure $ "Expected exception: " ++ show ex
  where isWanted = guard . (== ex)

testPasses = TestCase $ assertException DivideByZero (evaluate $ 5 `div` 0)
testFails  = TestCase $ assertException DivideByZero (evaluate $ 5 `div` 1)

main = runTestTT $ TestList [ testPasses, testFails ]
```

You can do something more fancy like using a predicate instead of explicit comparison if you like.

```
$ ./testex
### Failure in: 1                         
Expected exception: divide by zero
Cases: 2  Tried: 2  Errors: 0  Failures: 1
```

Note that `evaluate` here might get optimized away (see GHC ticket [#5129](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5129)), but for testing code in the `IO` monad this should work fine.

Comment: Nice example. Here is a modified version that prints if there is no exception or if it's another exception http://stackoverflow.com/a/33266991/3029422

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`assertRaises`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/testpack-2.1.2.1/docs/Test-HUnit-Tools.html#v:assertRaises) from [testpack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/testpack).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @sschaef Sorry, Haskell newbie here – why isn't testpack's `assertRaises` an answer to the question?

Comment: @akaihola: Ok, I was unclear. It provides an answer, but a link only answer, which is not very welcome on SO.

Comment: @sschaef I strongly disagree. The link provided here is NOT the answer. The answer is `There is a library function available that can be used to solve your problem`. The link only provides a reference (to the library docs). Therefore I conclude this is not at all a link-only question, even if it might look like it at first glance. You wouldn't expect the responder to post the whole library code, would you?

Comment: The package `testpack` is no longer maintained by its author.

Answer (score 1):

[hspec](http://hspec.github.io/) (or more precisely hspec-expectations) has [`shouldThrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-expectations-0.8.2/docs/Test-Hspec-Expectations.html#v:shouldThrow).