# How do I test for an error in Haskell?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, haskell, error-handling, hunit

I want to be able to make sure a function will throw an error when it receives and invalid value. For example, let says I have a function pos that only returns a positive number:

```
pos :: Int -> Int
pos x
   | x >= 0 = x
   | otherwise = error "Invalid Input"
```

This is a simplistic example, but I hope you get the idea.

I want to be able to write a test case that will expect an error and consider it a passing test. For example:

```
tests = [pos 1 == 1, assertError pos (-1), pos 2 == 2, assertError pos (-2)]
runTests = all (== True) tests
```

**[My Solution]**

This is what I ended up going with based on @hammar's comment.

```
instance Eq ErrorCall where
    x == y = (show x) == (show y)

assertException :: (Exception e, Eq e) => e -> IO a -> IO ()
assertException ex action =
    handleJust isWanted (const $ return ()) $ do
        action
        assertFailure $ "Expected exception: " ++ show ex
  where isWanted = guard . (== ex) 

assertError ex f = 
    TestCase $ assertException (ErrorCall ex) $ evaluate f

tests = TestList [ (pos 0) ~?= 0
                 , (pos 1) ~?= 1
                 , assertError "Invalid Input" (pos (-1))
                 ]   

main = runTestTT tests
```

Comment: `error` throws an `ErrorCall` exception. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147435/is-there-an-assertexception-in-any-of-the-haskell-test-frameworks/6147930#6147930) for how to test for exceptions using HUnit.

Comment: @hammar Ah, I wasn't sure if that would work in this case. Have you considered submitting that to the HUnit project? It would be nice if it was built in.

Comment: (N.B. `all (== True)` == `all id` == `and`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's solution defines `assertException`, but it looks like `Test.HUnit.Tools.assertRaises` from [testpack](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/testpack/latest/doc/html/Test-HUnit-Tools.html) is also usable here.

I added the `msg` argument to `assertError` to match how `assertRaises` works, and included selective imports so noobs like me can learn where commonly used things are imported from.

```
import Control.Exception (ErrorCall(ErrorCall), evaluate)
import Test.HUnit.Base  ((~?=), Test(TestCase, TestList))
import Test.HUnit.Text (runTestTT)
import Test.HUnit.Tools (assertRaises)

pos :: Int -> Int
pos x
   | x >= 0 = x
   | otherwise = error "Invalid Input"

instance Eq ErrorCall where
    x == y = (show x) == (show y)

assertError msg ex f = 
    TestCase $ assertRaises msg (ErrorCall ex) $ evaluate f

tests = TestList [
  (pos 0) ~?= 0
  , (pos 1) ~?= 1
  , assertError "Negative argument raises an error" "Invalid Input" (pos (-1))
  ]   

main = runTestTT tests
```

Comment: I love this answer! But do you have an idea on how else to implement this? The HUnit Tools library you're using here hasn't been maintained for years.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle errors in Haskell. Here is an overview: http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors

**[Edit]**

The first example shows how to catch errors, e.g.

```
half :: Int -> Int 
half x = if even x then x `div` 2 else error "odd"

main = do catch (print $ half 23) (\err -> print err)
```

That said, this kind of error handling is better suited for `IO` stuff, in pure code like yours Maybe, Either or something similar is usually a better choice. It could be as simple as...

```
pos :: Int -> Maybe Int
pos x
   | x >= 0 = Just x
   | otherwise = Nothing

tests = [pos 1 == Just 1
        ,pos (-1) == Nothing
        ,pos 2 == Just 2
        ,pos (-2) == Nothing
        ]

main = print $ and tests
```

... if you don't need an error type.

Comment: A useful link, but it doesn't answer the question of how to _test_ errors.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it requires me to change my functions to fit the tests, which is not really the purpose of tests. I want my functions to remain unchanged.

Comment: If your functions are pure, they should avoid to call `error`, if possible. If they are in `IO`, `catch` works fine. If this doesn't help, write a wrapper function transforming errors to `Maybe` or so. I guess for testing purposes you could even use the infamous `unsafePerformIO`.