# Haskell unit test for ErrorCall in HUnit

Tags: haskell, hunit

I've got a function:

```
unify :: [Constraint] -> [Substitution]
```

and in certain cases it throws exceptions with the `error` function:

```
error "Circular constraint"
```

I'm using `Test.HUnit` for unit testing and I'd like to make a test case that asserts these errors are thrown on certain inputs. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147435/is-there-an-assertexception-in-any-of-the-haskell-test-frameworks/6147930#6147930), which provides a way of testing for exceptions that are instances of `Eq`, but `error` seems to give [an `ErrorCall` exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:ErrorCall), which is not an instance of `Eq`, so I get the error:

```
No instance for (Eq ErrorCall)
  arising from a use of `assertException'
```

**How can I write a `TestCase` that asserts that `error` was called and (preferably) checks the message?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally I'd refactor your function into

```
unify' :: [Constraint] -> Maybe [Substitution]
unify' = -- your original function, but return Nothing instead of calling error,
         -- and return Just x when your original function would return x

unify = fromMaybe (error "Circular constraint") . unify'
```

I would then test `unify'` instead of testing `unify`.

If there was more than one possible error message, I would refactor it like this instead:

```
unify' :: [Constraint] -> Either String [Substitution]
    -- and return Left foo instead of calling error foo

unify = either error id . unify'
```

(Incidentally, if this is for a library other programmers will be using, some of them would prefer to call `unify'` instead of the partial function `unify`.)

---

If you can't refactor your code, I'd modify the code you link to, replacing `assertException` with:

```
assertErrorCall :: String -> IO a -> IO ()
assertErrorCall desiredErrorMessage action
    = handleJust isWanted (const $ return ()) $ do
        action
        assertFailure $ "Expected exception: " ++ desiredErrorMessage
  where isWanted (ErrorCall actualErrorMessage)
            = guard $ actualErrorMessage == desiredErrorMessage
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer b/c you both gave me a solution and proposed a better approach, thanks!

Comment: @aaronstacy Thanks for fixing the silly mistake in the code, btw.