# Testcase assertException

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to test if a function throws a certain exception.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147930/3029422) answer witch does this:

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Test.HUnit

assertException :: (Exception e, Eq e) => String -> e -> IO a -> IO ()
assertException preface expected action =
    handleJust isWanted (const $ return ()) $ do
        action
        assertFailure msg 
  where
    isWanted = guard . (== expected)
    msg = preface ++ "\nexpected exception: " ++ show expected

testPasses = TestCase $ assertException "Test1" DivideByZero (evaluate $ 5 `div` 0)
testFails  = TestCase $ assertException "Test2" DivideByZero (evaluate $ 5 `div` 1)

main = runTestTT $ TestList [ testPasses, testFails ]
```

witch, when run, shows:

```
### Failure in: 1
Test2
expected exception: divide by zero
Cases: 2  Tried: 2  Errors: 0  Failures: 1
```

but `assertException` does not show the actual exception or if there isn't one

Is there a way to be able to show the actual exception or the absence?
I tried wrapping action with `catch` but I don't know how to pass the actual exception to `msg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Test.HUnit
import GHC.Natural

assertException4 :: (Exception e, Eq e) => String -> e -> IO a -> IO ()
assertException4 preface expected action = do
  r <- catches
          (action >> return (Just "no exception thrown"))
          [ Handler (\e -> return $ if e == expected
                                       then Nothing
                                       else Just ("wrong exception thrown, expected " ++ show expected ++ ", got: " ++ show e))
          -- see the comments below about these two handlers:
          , Handler (\e -> throw (e :: AsyncException))
          , Handler (\(e::SomeException) -> return $ Just ("some other exception thrown: " ++ show e))
          ]
  case r of
    Nothing  -> return ()
    Just msg -> assertFailure (preface ++ ": " ++ msg)

test1 = TestCase $ assertException4 "Test1" DivideByZero (evaluate $ 5 `div` 0)
test2 = TestCase $ assertException4 "Test2" DivideByZero (evaluate $ 5 `div` 1)
test3 = TestCase $ assertException4 "Test3" DivideByZero (evaluate $ [1,2,3] !! 4)
test4 = TestCase $ assertException4 "Test4" DivideByZero (evaluate $ (fromInteger (0 - 3) :: Natural) )

main = runTestTT $ TestList [ test1, test2, test3, test4 ]
```

The four test cases are:

1. DivideByZero exception thrown - test should pass
2. No exception thrown - test should fail
3. Wrong exception thrown (of a different type) - test should fail
4. Wrong exception thrown (of the same type) - test should fail

Note that you have to have a different catch handler for exceptions which are not of the same type as the target exception.

Also, I re-throw any AsyncException since that is what HUnit does in `performTestCase` [(link)](https://github.com/hspec/HUnit/blob/master/Test/HUnit/Lang.hs#L80-92)
Hitting Control-C will cause an AsyncException, for instance.

Note that uncaught exceptions will be reported as Errors by HUnit, and the exception will be printed out. You can test this out by removing the handlers for AsyncException and SomeException.

Comment: Thanks for your complete response

Comment: Is there a way to pass a `custom exception` instead of `Exception`? Like this `data CustomException= MyException deriving (Show, Typeable) instance Exception CustomException`. When I try it I get the error: `No instance for (Eq CustomException)`.

Comment: Just add/derive an Eq instance for your CustomException - there's only one value in that type. DivideByZero has type ArithException and there are 3 other possible ArithExceptions - that's why you need the equality test.